# ef core linq filtered child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem with a linq query.
I have 3 entities: 
user, target and results.
each user can have multiple (or no) targets and each target can have multiple (or no) results
I want a query that returns all users including possible targets and possible results. And that's working great. But now I want to include filters to filter the targets and results. So that the query only returns users, targets and results matching these criteria.

```
public class User
{
  public ICollection Targets {get;set;}
  public string otherProperty {get;set;}
}

public class Target
{
  public ICollection Results {get;set;}
  public User user {get;set;}
  public string Language {get;set;}
}

public class Result
{
  public Target Target {get;set;}
  public int score {get;set;}
}
```

Any EF core linq specialists that can help me?

Kind regards,
Robrecht

**EDIT 1**

```
var query =
from auditUser in _auditUserRepository.GetAll().Include(u => u.user)
.WhereIf(!input.Group.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), u => u.Group == input.Group)
.WhereIf(!input.Filter.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), u => u.user.FullName.ToLower().Contains(input.Filter.ToLower()))
select auditUser;

var results = query
.Include(u => u.Targets)
.ThenInclude(t => t.AuditResults)
.PageBy(input)
.ToListAsync();

await query
.SelectMany(u => u.Targets)
.WhereIf(!input.Language.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), t => t.Target == input.Language)
.SelectMany(t => t.AuditResults)
.WhereIf(input.From != null, r => r.CompletionDate >= input.From)
.WhereIf(input.To != null, r => r.CompletionDate <= input.From)
.LoadAsync();
```

This is what I have so for but it has 2 problems:

1. When there is no result for a, the target is not included. It seems that it include or theninclude creates inner joins instead of left joins.
2. This doesn't filter on language or date.

Comment: Can you show your current query and some example filter criteria?

Comment: If you mean filtered includes, they've never been supported in EF, and still aren't (including the latest EF Core 2.0). The solution is projection (`select`) query.

Comment: Hi Ivan, can you show an example of the projection query?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a ViewModel class with the properties you want. Example:

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
    [Display(Name = "Other")]
    public string otherProperty {get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Possible Targets")]
    public List<Target> targets {get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Possible Results")]
    public List<Result> results{get; set;}
    }
```

Then in your "repository" class you can create a method to filter the results.

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetUserViewModelBy(int scoreFilter, string filter1= "", string filter2)
        {
            IQueryable<Result> query = _context.Results.Where(i => i.score==scoreFilter)).Include(x => x.Target)
                                                               .Include(x => x.Target.Results.ToList())
                                                               .Include(x => x.User)
.Include(x=>x.User.Targets.Where(i=>i.Language.ToLower().Contains(filter1)).ToList());

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter2))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Target.Language.ToLower().Contains(filter2));
            }

            return query.Select(x => new UserViewModel()
            {
                otherProperty = x.User.otherProperty,
                targets = x.User.targets,
                results = x.Results

            }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: How would the filters look if the score filter is optional. and when it's not present I want all users and targets also the ones witouth results.